# Erro em lista/BD

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou com um erro neste trecho (aparece o *trecho todo grifado de vermelho*), o que está errado?

```
    lista.setOnLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){ //clique longo, para selecionar a linha
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            medicamento = (Medicamentos)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Java:

```
package com.example.vanessa.projetoinicial_vanessa;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.vanessa.projetoinicial_vanessa.BD.MedicamentosBd;
import com.example.vanessa.projetoinicial_vanessa.model.Medicamentos;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CadastroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lista;
MedicamentosBd bdMed;
ArrayList<Medicamentos> lista_Madicamentos;
Medicamentos medicamento;
ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);

    //Ao clicar no botão Cadastrar (da tela 2 Cadastro), deve ir para tela Formulario
    Button botaoCadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cadastrar);
    botaoCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CadastroActivity.this, FormularioActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_Madicamentos);
    registerForContextMenu(lista);


    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            Medicamentos medicamentoEscolhido = (Medicamentos) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); //retorna o item, que é convertido (cast) para Medicamentos

            Intent i = new Intent(CadastroActivity.this, FormularioActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("medicamento-escolhido", medicamentoEscolhido);
        }
    });

    lista.setOnLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){ //clique longo, para selecionar a linha
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            medicamento = (Medicamentos)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            return false;
        }
    });




}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    MenuItem menuDelete = menu.add("Deletar Este Medicamento");
    menuDelete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            bdMed = new MedicamentosBd(CadastroActivity.this);
            bdMed.deletarMedicamento(medicamento);
            bdMed.close();
            carregarMedicamento(); //assim que deleta, ele carrega para atualizar a lista
            return true;
        }
    });
}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    carregarMedicamento();
}

public void carregarMedicamento(){ //carregar a lista de medicamentos
    bdMed = new MedicamentosBd(CadastroActivity.this);
    lista_Madicamentos = bdMed.getLista();
    bdMed.close();
    if(lista_Madicamentos != null){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Medicamentos>(CadastroActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lista_Madicamentos);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
}
```

Erro:

```
error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnItemLongClickListener> cannot be converted to OnLongClickListener
```

---

```
setOnLongClickListener (android.view.View.OnLongClickListener) in View cannot be applied
to (anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener)
```

Comment: Buguei. Estou enferrujado de Android. Vou apagar minha resposta e deixar para alguém responder.

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma:

```
lista.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v)
            {
                .
                .
                .
            }
        });
```

Espero que ajude!

Answer (score 0):

Oh erro está na incompatibilidade de você tentar passar o `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener`para a interface `setOnLongClickListener`. Visto que você quer capturar o **medicamento** que foi clicado, então você tem que usar o `lista.setOnItemLongClickListener`, é só mudar o **set**.

Provavelmente ficaria assim:

```
lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            medicamento = (Medicamentos)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            return false;
        }
    });
```